# Generic Method Covariance - valid restriction or compiler oversight?

Tags: java, generics, covariance

Does anyone know the definitive answer to why the following isn't allowed by the java compiler?

```
class BaseClass {

      public <T extends Number> T getNumber(){
            return null;
      }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass{

      @Override
      public <T extends Integer> T getNumber(){
            return null;
      }

}
```

this causes the compiler to complain with:

"The method getNumber() of type SubClass must override a superclass method"

Now, when I put this to my colleagues some have tried to explain that it will cause confusion with the compiler. However, as was also pointed out the following, which is conceptually similar, is compilable.

```
class BaseClass<T extends Number> {
      public T getNumber(){
            return null;

      }
}


class SubClass<T extends Integer> extends BaseClass<T>{
      @Override   
      public  T getNumber(){
            return null;

      }
}
```

This can be abused if the subclass calls the super implementation, but the compiler provides a warning to this effect. My only conclusion is that this is a compiler oversight on the part of folks at Sun (can't bring myself to say Oracle :-S).

Anyone have the definitive answer to this one?

Comment: Aah yes, we all love Sun but the Oracle? (Let me shut up now)....lol

Comment: Note that `<T extends Integer>` does not make much sense since `Integer` is final. You could for instance change it from `Integer` to `BigInteger` or something...

Answer (score 5):

Suppose it would indeed be allowed to add more restrictions to the type parameter on a derived class.

Then what if your class also had a `<T extends Number> void setNumber(T number)` method?

```
BaseClass foo = new SubClass();
long longValue = 42;
foo.<Long>setNumber(longValue);
```

The above would be accepted by the compiler because BaseClass.setNumber accepts any type parameter derived from `Number`. But the actual instance only accepts integers!

You could argue that if the type parameter is only used for the return value, it should automatically be considered covariant. But then the compiler would have to make sure that you don't use the type parameter inside the method body in a non-covariant way.

(In [C# 4.0 this was actually solved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_4.0#Covariant_and_contravariant_generic_type_parameters), but it involves explicitly marking your type parameters as covariant or contravariant with the `out` and `in` keywords. It was not something that could simply be allowed by the compiler without changing the language.)

Comment: My thinking was also along these lines - make the compiler more sophisticated to allow the author to use the language to the limit, but safeguard him/her from potential errors...

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your issue:

When I implemented your first portion of source code and compiled using `javac *.java`, it compiled fine. However, if I changed your `SubClass.getNumber()` method to do this...

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
  * @see constraint.base.BaseClass#getNumber()
  */
 @Override
 public <T extends Number> T getNumber() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return super.getNumber();
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
SubClass.java:18: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Number
                return super.getNumber();
                                      ^
1 error
```

The reason for the code above is that by calling `super.getNumber()`, the compiler doesn't have any input that infer type `T` hence it cannot determine what `T` will be returned by `super.getNumber()` and, thus it can't satisfy the return type with `SubClass.getNumber()`

Now, in order to have obtained the error from the compiler, `"The method getNumber() of type SubClass must override a superclass method"`, your `BaseClass` should have been **abstract** along with it's `getNumber()` method.

As for the 2nd piece of code you've provided, the subclass can, in effect, call `super.getNumber()` as the compiler will know (on compiling) that the SubClass's Generic Parameter Type is inferred to the Parameter Type of `BaseClass`.

Besides that, I really didn't know what you were trying to ask.

Comment: If I remove the @Override annotation then I can compile successfully (win/mac jdk). However in eclipse the following error is reported:    "Name clash: The method getNumber() of type SubClass has the same erasure as getNumber() of type BaseClass but does not override it"

Comment: If the @Override annotation is present then I get the following error: "The method getNumber() of type SubClass must override or implement a supertype method"

Comment: If I remove the @Override annotation and initialise the method with an Integer type argument in the subclass then it compiles fine, however if I then instantiate SubClass and try to invoke a method the compiler returns the following error: 

reference to getNumber is ambiguous, both method <T>getNumber() in test2.BaseClass and method <T>getNumber() in test2.SubClass match
  sc.<Integer>getNumber();

If I initialise with a Number type then it compiles fine.

Comment: I see your point that calling super.getNumber() might confuse the compiler, but then if I didn't then I don't see any reason why the overridden method couldn't simply replace the definition of T in the subclass. It is rare to need such functionality, but I did find such a situation and then discovered this wasn't allowed.

Comment: `If I remove the @Override annotation then I can compile successfully (win/mac jdk).` Your code compiled fine with the `@Override` annotation. I don't follow what you meant. Bear in mind that Eclipse has its own means of "cleaning" code (forgot the term).

Comment: I'm not sure how we are getting different compilation results here - which jdk version/plaform are you running?

Comment: I'm running java JDK 1.6.0_21 Sun JDK for Windows and I'm compiling using `javac *.java`.

Answer (score 0):

@Wim Coenen provided a good answer.

Here is a small clarification.

If this would compile, what would you expect happened:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class BaseClass {

    public <T extends Number> T getNumber(T n) {
        System.out.println("Int value: " + n.intValue());
        return n;
    }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public <T extends BigInteger> T getNumber(T n) {
        System.out.println("Int value: " + n.intValue());

        // BigInteger specific!
        System.out.println("Bit count: " + n.bitCount());
        return n;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseClass sub = new SubClass();

        // sub looks like a BaseClass...
        // ...but since it's a SubClass it expects a BigInteger!
        sub.getNumber(new Integer(5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you've just proved exactly what I said with code example (which I also did, but not fully posted in my case).

Comment: Ok. If you say so... Not sure I understand your answer though. Why do you keep mentioning `super` in every section?

Comment: I was showing that his code posted compiled fine in when compiled outside of Eclipse (since he `return null` but by allowing `super.getNumber()` that's where the issues starts.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no covariance here. Covariance means 'varies with', and it refers to the return type varying as the containing class type. That's not happening here. There is no 'co' in your covariance.

Comment: I think you're avoiding the question.

Comment: Not in the slightest. The OP is simply misusing terminology. That is the source of his confusion.